# setting Defaut value for Date time column

Tags: sql, sql-server

UI for detting default value:

[image: UI for detting default value]

greetings , i want to know what is the SQL script for doing the process in the attached image , setting the default value for a date column , i am using that query

```
alter table email alter column InDate datetime not null set Default getdate ()
```

but it give me the following error

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Default'.
```

so i searched and found that you can do it using the UI

Comment: Have you tried putting parentheses around the SQL `getdate()` -> `... set Default (getdate ())`

Comment: i did , but it didn't work and gave the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below alter syntax,

**Syntax**

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_NAME
DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR myColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find what exactly that, or any other such as setting `identity column` you can reverse engineer the process by setting it up in `Management Studio` and then generate the script.
Go to the design mode and make the change, then right click on **any** column name, and select the `Generate Change Script` option. Whatever changes you made can be generated as script, so that you can find out what needs to be done by yourself.

Ex.

[image]

It has some additional information , but you can easily spot the required query (see the image)

[image]